# Insert spatial record to posgres/postgis tables using PyQGIS failed

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I try to insert spatial record to postgres/postgis using PyQGIS but I don't get that record on my postgre/postgis table after the execution, and I don't get any error too. 
Here my code :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO gis.tx_bidang2(numb, d_nop, d_luas, geom, aktor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s);"
        data =(91,'727100000000000000', 0,'0106000020EE7F00000100000001030000000100000006000000A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241433A6F613FDF2841B818D26D82E76241D8264A6693EF2841AF4D940C52E76241D9B589E2E6F22841B1DCD306E8E762411CF0F8F3C2ED2841F5A58216D5E86241A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241','septin',)
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_pbb' host=localhost port=5433 user='postgres' password='septin'")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, data)
```

Any ideas ?,

---

I got it done, here my script :

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'db_pbb' host = 'localhost' port = '5433' user = 'postgres' password = 'septin'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql2 = 'INSERT INTO gis.tx_bidang2(numb, d_nop, d_luas, geom, aktor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s);'
    data = (100, '727100000000000000', 0,'0106000020EE7F00000100000001030000000100000006000000A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241433A6F613FDF2841B818D26D82E76241D8264A6693EF2841AF4D940C52E76241D9B589E2E6F22841B1DCD306E8E762411CF0F8F3C2ED2841F5A58216D5E86241A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241','septin')
    cur.execute(sql2, data)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: conn.commit() possibly.

Comment: @JohnBarça where should I put conn.commit() ?
I've try to put it after cur.execute(sql, data)
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know then . Generally, updates and inserts require an explicit commit after the execute. Are you sure there are no errors?

Comment: @JohnBarça yups, there are no notifications of errors, but then I try and try again and finally got it done.

Here my code, you're right it use commit :

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it done, here my script :

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'db_pbb' host = 'localhost' port = '5433' user = 'postgres' password = 'septin'")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql2 = 'INSERT INTO gis.tx_bidang2(numb, d_nop, d_luas, geom, aktor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s);'
data = (100,'727100000000000000',0,'0106000020EE7F00000100000001030000000100000006000000A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241433A6F613FDF2841B818D26D82E76241D8264A6693EF2841AF4D940C52E76241D9B589E2E6F22841B1DCD306E8E762411CF0F8F3C2ED2841F5A58216D5E86241A0D5979A27E02841AAA0D59F4DE86241','septin')
cur.execute(sql2, data)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```